# Hyperlinking to bookmark on pmf or mxd?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, pdf, arcgis-publisher

Can anyone advise how do I do a hyperlink that directly link to a bookmarked area of a pmf or mxd? Something like what we do to hyperlink to a specific page in pdf.

For example, I have a mxd call BD_WORLD with Regional_View as one of the bookmark.

SO something like this will be my hyperlink: 
\\serverABC\GIS\WORLD_MXD\BD_WORLD.mxd#Regional _View

Preferably, I would like to do it in attribute table, if possible.

PS: using 9.3.1, with only Arcview, Spatial Analyst and Publisher.

Comment: +1 Nifty idea, but if you're adding a bookmark to the attribute table, wouldn't it be just as easy to select that record and zoom to extent as a work-around?

Comment: Roy, this link which I am trying to do will be in SharePoint, and it will be attached to an image, so if I Click on that image in SP, it will open up that mxd with that bookmarked view. that's what i am trying to do.

Comment: In that use case, you'd just have to save your mxd several different times.  The extent at which you save the map will be your 'bookmark'.

Comment: @ Roy - have you looked at the suggestion I posted?  You might also find this to be rather handy for large study areas.  It's a fabulous little tool!!  Check out the tutorial at the link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will help you, but what about creating a map book?  [HERE'S A LINK](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=2152) to a free ESRI seminar on how to do this.  Basically, you just create a shapefile and make rectangles around your areas of interest and set everything up in the data driven pages menus.  You can name your various areas in the attribute table, impliment varying scales for each area, display a title for each area directly linked to your attribute table, impliment rotation angles based on an attribute column, etc, etc.  Your better off just watching the seminar (as opposed to me rambling on about it) .  It's really not that complicated.  Basically, you will be able to flip though your pages/distinct areas and have the scales, rotations, map titles, etc set up to your liking.  This is a really great little tool for large study areas.  If you want to display an inset map, the extent rectangles will even move & change scales accordingly with each page in your map book.  I hope this accomplishes what you're after.  Take care.